# How to get richtextbox text into textblock in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

how to get richtextbox text into textblock in windows phone application using C#

I did this for windows phone application

```
  private void OnMessageReceived(string message)
    {
        var paragraph = new Paragraph();

        var runs = new List<Inline>();

        foreach (var word in message.Split(' '))
        {
            Uri uri;

            if (Uri.TryCreate(word, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) ||
               (word.StartsWith("www.") || word.EndsWith(".com") || word.Contains("@") && Uri.TryCreate("http://" + word, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)))
            {
                var link = new Hyperlink();
                link.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = word });
                link.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var hyperLink = (sender as Hyperlink);
                    new WebBrowserTask() { Uri = uri }.Show();
                };

                runs.Add(link);

            }
            else
            {
                runs.Add(new Run() { Text = word });
            }

            runs.Add(new Run() { Text = " " });
        }

        foreach (var run in runs)
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);

        txtDisplayText.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

    }
```

"txtDiplayText" is a RichTextBox
i want that RichTextBox data to TextBlock

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `RichTextBox` as follows:

```
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        rtb.FontSize = 12;
        rtb.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        rtb.Width = this.Width;
        Run run = new Run();
        run.Text = "Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.Hello World.";
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        para.Inlines.Add(run);
        rtb.Blocks.Add(para);
```

then give a name to the control and add it to the `textblock` you want.

Hope it helps!